# JavaScript / JQ - scroll to bottom of div with images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a simple chat functionality which were working fine till I add functionality to upload images.
I want when the page is loaded first time, my div scroll to be on the bottom.

This is how I set the scroll to bottom of the div (this method is invoked in document ready function.)

```
function calculateScrollPosition() {
    if ($("#history-info").attr("data-chunk") == 0) {
        $('.chat-history').animate({scrollTop: $('.chat-history').prop('scrollHeight')}, 10);
    }

}
```

the css of .chat-history

```
.chat .chat-history {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f4f7f6;
}
```

Every refresh set the scroll on a different position (depending when the images are ready) but never to the bottom. How can I make the scroll to be on the bottom of the div?

NB. the content is loaded and appended with Ajax

[image]

Comment: Hello, how did you handle the page full-loadeded event in your code ?

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez I don't :) How shoud I ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using AJAX when docoment ready to query for json objects with I modify to html tags.

Comment: that's good you mentioned this part because it's an important one.. It would be better if you share also this part to check if there is no code ordering issues